# Как завершить все события и циклы внутри функции jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем добрый день. Недавно изучи канвас, и теперь пробую сделать его адаптивным, просто чтобы потренироваться.
Проблема при resize() запускается функция Start(), с новыми параметрами длины и высоты (т.к. не получалось менять их динамически. В этом канвасе несколько таймеров и событий, ну и после ресайза та функция запускается еще раз, но таймеры и события не перестают работать - картинки накладываются одна на другую, и при большом количестве ресайзов начинает виснуть, ну логично. Так как мне отключать все события внутри Start при ресайзе окна?
Вот ВЕСЬ код:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var x1;
    var y1;
    var ww = window.innerWidth;
    var wh = window.innerHeight;
    function selectGoing(x, y){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (y - x + 1)) + x;
    }
    function selectshag(x, y){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (y - x + 1)) + x;
    }
    function Start(){
        var canvas = $('.canv').get(0);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var array_points = [];
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
        for (var i = 0; i <= 150; i++) {
            array_points[i] = [];
            array_points[i]['x'] = Math.random()/1*ww;
            array_points[i]['y'] = Math.random()/1*wh;
            array_points[i]['z'] = selectGoing(0, 7);
            ctx.fillRect(array_points[i]['x'], array_points[i]['y'], 5, 5);
        }
        setInterval(function(){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,ww,wh);
            for (var i = 0; i <= 150; i++) {
                var shag = 1;
                switch(array_points[i]['z']) {
                  case 0: //вверх
                    if (array_points[i]['x'] + 0 < ww-3 && array_points[i]['y'] - shag < 0) {
                            array_points[i]['y'] = wh-3;
                        }
                        array_points[i]['x'] += 0;
                        array_points[i]['y'] -= shag;

                  break;
                  case 1: //вверх вправо
                        if(array_points[i]['x'] + shag/2 > ww-3){
                            array_points[i]['x'] = 0;
                        }
                        if(array_points[i]['y'] - shag/2 < 0){
                            array_points[i]['y'] = wh-3;
                        }
                        array_points[i]['x'] += shag/2;
                        array_points[i]['y'] -= shag/2;
                  break;
                  case 2: //вправо
                    if(array_points[i]['x'] +  shag > ww-3){
                        array_points[i]['x'] = 0;
                    }
                     array_points[i]['x'] += shag;
                     array_points[i]['y'] += 0;
                  break;
                  case 3: //вниз вправо
                    if(array_points[i]['x'] +  shag/2 > ww-3){
                        array_points[i]['x'] = 0;
                    }
                    if(array_points[i]['y'] + shag/2 > wh-3){
                        array_points[i]['y'] = 0;
                    }
                     array_points[i]['x'] += shag/2;
                    array_points[i]['y'] += shag/2;
                  break;
                  case 4: //вниз
                  if (array_points[i]['y'] +  shag > wh-3) {
                       array_points[i]['y'] = 0;
                    }
                     array_points[i]['x'] -= 0;
                        array_points[i]['y'] += shag;
                  break;
                  case 5: //вниз вліво
                    if(array_points[i]['x'] -  shag/2 < 3){
                        array_points[i]['x'] = ww-3
                    }
                    if(array_points[i]['y'] + shag/2 > wh-3){
                        array_points[i]['y'] = 0
                    }
                    array_points[i]['x'] -= shag/2;
                    array_points[i]['y'] += shag/2;
                  break;
                  case 6: //вліво
                   if (array_points[i]['x'] - shag < 3) {
                        array_points[i]['x'] = ww-3;
                    }
                    array_points[i]['x'] -= shag;
                    array_points[i]['y'] -= 0;
                  break;
                  case 7: //вверх вліво
                    if(array_points[i]['x'] -  shag/2 < 3 ){
                        array_points[i]['x'] = ww-3;
                    }
                    if(array_points[i]['y'] - shag/2 < 3){
                        array_points[i]['y'] = wh-3;
                    }
                    array_points[i]['x'] -= shag/2;
                    array_points[i]['y'] -= shag/2;
                  break;

                }
                ctx.fillRect(array_points[i]['x'], array_points[i]['y'], 5, 5);
            }
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,ww,wh);
            ctx.beginPath();
            for (var i = 0; i <= 150; i++) {
                ctx.fillRect(array_points[i]['x'], array_points[i]['y'], 5, 5);
                /*ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
                ctx.fillText(array_points[i]['z'], array_points[i]['x'], array_points[i]['y']);*/
                var x2 = +array_points[i]['x'];
                var y2 = +array_points[i]['y'];
                var length = Math.pow(Math.pow((x1 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y2), 2), 0.5);
                if (length < 150) {
                    ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
                    ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
                }
            }

            ctx.stroke();

        }, 10);
        $('.canv').on('mousemove', function(event){
            x1 = event.offsetX;
            y1 = event.offsetY;
        });

    }
    function ResizeAll(){
        ww = window.innerWidth;
        wh = window.innerHeight;
        $('.canv').attr('width', ww);
        $('.canv').attr('height', wh);
        $('.canv').css('width', ww);
        $('.canv').css('height', wh);
        Start();
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        ResizeAll();
        $(window).resize(function(){
            ResizeAll();
        });
    });

</script>
            <canvas class="canv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;border: 1px solid black; margin: auto; background-color: black;" width="ww" height="wh">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var resize = function(e){
  console.log(e);
};

(function(){
  var time;
  window.onresize = function(e){
    if (time)
      clearTimeout(time);
    time = setTimeout(function(){
      resize(e);
    },1000);
  }
})();
```

Как только Вы перестанете изменять размеры окна, через секунду после этого произойдет вызов вашей функции